# react-i18next cannot resolve key

Tags: internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I have a problem with react-i18next not resolving my keys, so everything I get as an output are the keys themself.

I had to embed my project as gui project to a VisualStudio solution. Running my original project works just fine, the solution project in contrast cannot resolve the key part of my translate function call.

```
t('user:KEY_CONSTANT') //output: KEY_CONSTANT
```

My i18n.config looks like this:

```
i18n
    .use(XHR)
    .init({
        lng: i18nHelper.languageDetector(),
        load: 'currentOnly',
        fallbackLng: 'en-US',
        backend: {
            loadPath: 'i18n/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
        },

        ns: ['admin', 'user'],
        defaultNS: 'admin',
        debug: false,

        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
            formatSeparator: ',',
            format: function (vale, format, lng) {
                if (format === 'uppercase') return value.toUpperCase();
                return value;
            }
        }
    });
```

When embedding the project in the solution, I had to change webpacks output folder, which I think is the actual reason of malfunctioning, but I can't find where exact the problem occurs. I tried changing the loadPath, but if thats the source of failure, I just didn't try it the right way :S

My project tree looks like:

```
Solution
|-gui
|  |-src
|    |-i18n
|      |-de-DE(containing the german admin.json and user.json files)
|      |-en-US(containing the english admin.json and user.json files) 
|    |-utils
|      |-i18n.js
|-out
|  |-prgFiles
|    |-html
|      |-i18n(contains same items as i18n under src)
```

In my old project, the webpack output was '/dist/' on the same level as src, in the solution, '../out/prgFiles/html'.

admin.json right now contains no keys at all, user.json contains the keys just like you'd expect:

```
{
    "KEY_CONSTANT": "Actual string value"
}
```

As said, I tried around a bit with path changes, checked for translate, i18next and i18next-Provider beeing found and everythings fine. It just cant resolve KEY_CONSTANT to the actual value.

Do you have an idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set debug option to true in i18next init -> i bet you will get an error stating something like backendConnector failed to load namespace user...

make sure the clientside is able to load the translations (the webpack-dev server does a good job in doing so - but in production you will need to serve those file yourself)

Comment: I tried so, and the error I get is 'i18next::translator: missingKey en-US user <KEY>'. I have no ideo on how to serve those files myself. Any suggestions?

Comment: a long time away from .net side...so can't help you much there...so no plan how you spawn your server there - only alternative i can give you https://locize.com the service tier of i18next - you could manage your translations there and load them from there. So no own server needed.

Comment: The solution I had to wrap around my project was generated, and it seems it also delivers a way to render my strings directly to my page. Even though I have to add all the strings again, it seems to be the way to go. So even if the answer is not a perfect resolution to my problem, it helped me a lot, so I accepted it as answer. Thanks for your help!